# Cascade ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Try to implement a few ajax requests, each depend from previous, short example:

```
     $.post("/?an=biki&photo=39",  {photo: 39}, function (response) {
                    $("#sent_sms_code").live("click", function (another_response) {
                        var phone = $("#phone_vote").val();
                        $.post("/?an=biki_make_sms&photo=39",  {phone: phone}, function (code) { });                         
                    });
     });
```

How to perfom this code in best practices, without subquery?  Thanks

Comment: An event handler inside a callback is generally not a good idea, neither is using the deprecated and removed live() method. You should explain better what exactly it is you're trying to do, and perhaps someone will come up with a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The function you've written is not chained AJAX. It seems you just want to bind event when first AJAX call is made.
Why not do this?

```
var AJAXResponse = null;

$.post("/?an=biki&photo=39",  {photo: 39}, function (response) {
    AJAXResponse = response;
 });

 $("#sent_sms_code").on("click", function() {
    bindAjaxEvent();
 });

 function bindAjaxEvent() {
    if(AJAXResponse !== null) {
        var phone = $("#phone_vote").val();
        $.post("/?an=biki_make_sms&photo=39",  {phone: phone}, function (code) { });
    }
 }
```

This way event on element is always bound. THe event only checks if there's AJAXResponse or not and invokes the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain promises so that when one promise is returned, it triggers the next.

I haven't done this myself with jQuery, but I have done it with Angular.js

The jquery promise documentation is here
http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Here's my guess at how you'd use it.

```
var first_post = function(){$.post(... }
var second_post = function(){$.post(... }

first_post.promise().done(function(){ second_post)
```

However, are you sure you want to chain promises or ajax calls to the same host? Seems like you're better off doing the second call on the server rather than returning and then making another ajax request. I assume you aren't able to change the server-side code, but just thought I'd mention it to make sure.

Comment: but my second request initilize not when first done, but when user click $("#sent_sms_code").live("click")....thanks